# mingw is having issues when i try to link external libraries

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw-w64

when i try to link libraries `-l./lib` and then `-llibglad.a` it shows this error.

```
g++ -g -std=c++17  -I./include -L./lib -libglad -libglfw3dll -libopengl32 src/main.cpp -o main
C:/MinGW/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -libglad
C:/MinGW/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -libglfw3dll
C:/MinGW/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -libopengl32
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:17: main] Error 1
```

can anyone please tell whats the problem?

makefile ~

```
CXX     := g++
CXX_FLAGS  := -g -std=c++17 #-Wextra -Wall

SRC     := src
INCLUDE := ./include
LIB     := ./lib

LIBRARIES := -libglad -libglfw3dll -libopengl32
EXECUTABLE  := main

all:./$(EXECUTABLE)

run: all
    ./$(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE):$(SRC)/*.cpp
     $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) -L$(LIB) $(LIBRARIES) $^ -o $@
```

Comment: Your libraries aren't specified correctly. You need to do it in the form: `-lglad -lglfw3dll -lopengl32` - i.e. remove the 'lib' prefix.

You'll also likely need to put the libraries that your source files depends on after the $^ as you'll probably get 'undefined reference' errors from the compilation.

Comment: thanks for the help  there are no error related to that. now there is a new error `src/main.cpp:1:14: fatal error: glad/glad.h: No such file or directory
     #include <glad/glad.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:17: main] Error 1` how to solve this one .. sorry i am not so experienced ..